# deploying to netflify issue react app with tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, netlify

I tried to deploy my react app(which is contains tailwindCss) to netlify
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyBM4.png)

here is my code https://github.com/sardor1215/muzifyNews

Comment: Add proper error log, describe the issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing your question is very unclear.

What I did understand is that Your code somewhere the path is not correct. So check your code once and remove all your errors and revert back if not solved your problem with detailed information.